# lambda calculus example quenstion

Tags: lambda-calculus

(λy.x z)c

I think a answer about this problem is x z.

If it is correct, why (λy.x z)c = x c is incorrect? 
In this case, I refer to (λy.x z) = (λy.x)z = x. So I calculate it in the parenthesis first.

Answer (score 0):

`(λy.x z) c` is not a problem, it is a λ-term.
You refer to `λy.x z = (λy.x) z` but there is no way to move the parentheses, otherwise it would mean they were useless.

```
λy. x z
```

Means the function which takes `y` as argument and returns `x` applied to `z`.
While `(λy.x) z` means the function which takes `y` as argument and returns `x`, the whole thing applied to `z`. Why would those two things be the same?
(They are not.)

Comment: 1. (λy.x z) c is not a problem: why? Isn't y substituted by c?                                                
2. You refer to λy.x z = (λy.x) z: no. I refer to  (λy.x z) = (λy.x)z. Parentheses should be around lambda.

Comment: `λy.x z` isn't substituted by `c`, it is _applied_ to `c`. Also I'm sorry to say `λy. x z` and `(λy. x z)` are the same term… like in `(x + y) × z` you have `x + y`, the same as `(x + y)`.